# Checking for empty arrays: count vs empty

Tags: php, arrays, performance, standards, semantics

This question on '[How to tell if a PHP array is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-tell-if-a-php-array-is-empty/2216062#2216062)' had me thinking of this question

Is there a reason that `count` should be used instead of `empty` when determining if an array is empty or not?

My personal thought would be if the 2 are equivalent for the case of empty arrays you should use `empty` because it gives a boolean answer to a boolean question. From the question linked above, it seems that `count($var) == 0` is the popular method. To me, while technically correct, makes no sense. E.g. **Q: $var, are you empty? A: 7**. Hmmm...

Is there a reason I should use `count == 0` instead or just a matter of personal taste?

As pointed out by others in comments for a now deleted answer, `count` will have performance impacts for large arrays because it will have to count all elements, whereas `empty` can stop as soon as it knows it isn't empty. So, if they give the same results in this case, but `count` is potentially inefficient, why would we ever use `count($var) == 0`?

Comment: I'm assuming your intention is to limit the conversation exclusively to arrays, but it might be worth noting that the game changes completely if you are working with objects (e.g., that implement Countable, Iterator, etc.).

Comment: An empty array is equal to `false` in PHP - no need for `empty()` or `count()`.

Comment: @Cobby Code please.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 As in, just do: `if (!$myArray) { echo "array is empty"; }`
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c0e7be87672996c249aa39ae22dc25f1caaee48

Comment: Nowadays, the popular option in the linked question is using `empty()`.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I generally use `empty`. Im not sure why people would use count really - If the array is large then count takes longer/has more overhead. If you simply need to know whether or not the array is empty then use empty.

Comment: These functions indeed differ when the array is *not* empty.

Comment: @Jacco: Im not disputing that. But if youre testing it its empty, i dont see what relevance that has - its a question with a boolean result which is what the function will return. In regards to what is considered empty in dont see how those criteria would produce the wrong answer unless the var your testing isnt an array inwhich case thats an entirely different issue.

Comment: @prodigitalson I would say that count is `O(1)`, since PHP stores the number of elements internally. Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5835419/592454

Comment: @eliton: but still - even in if there is no or little difference in performance why use count if you dont need the count?

Comment: also, using `count()` with forms having multiple [inputs with same name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7880656/2534513) will count empty fields,  leading to errors.

Comment: @prodigitalson: The reason is simple. It depends on what you need. Main problem is, that even array(0) or array('') is considered empty, however count returns 1. Question is, if you want to consider this as empty, or you want to distinct really empty array from array(0).

Comment: This is the best answer for standard arrays, but not for collections as a broader class of objects.

Comment: empty() is too forgiving of errors. I just spent 2 hours debugging a subclass that tested empty() on a private member variable of its superclass (the scope of the superclass's member variable SHOULD have been protected, but empty() returned no errors — the result was simply that something that should have happened, didn't happen: the non-existence of the member variable in the subclass was treated exactly the same way as though this member variable, an array, was empty — i.e., as though it had no elements). This is problematic, and another example of PHP being too forgiving.

Comment: @MatthewSlyman in that case i would normally use `isset($this->member) && !empty($this->member)`

Comment: You don't want to use `empty()` because it's shit. Too forgiving, has odd behavior like returning false even for `string('0')`, etc. If you have an array and want to check whether it's empty either use `count() === 0` which is nicely readable and clear or - if you *absolutely need* speed - use `$array === []` (aka ``$array === array()``) which is almost as fast as `empty()`. Using `count()` has, however, one more advantage - if you decide at a later time that you want to swap your array for something smarter (as in object implementing at least `Countable`) you won't have to change anything.

Comment: I just found out that `count(0) === int(1)`. I got a function that returned 0 instead of an empty string on error. This might be the implementation fault, but I would expect a "loose equality for an empty string (false)" will `count` as 0. Maybe the best is `$array === []` and using neither of both

Comment: @micropro.cz: "even array(0) or array('') is considered empty": Don't know about historically, but checking with PHP 7.0, empty() returns false for both of these as expected.

Answer (score 55):

I was curious to see which one was actually faster so I made a simple script to benchmark those functions.

```
<?php

function benchmark($name, $iterations, $action){
    $time=microtime(true);
    for($i=0;$i<=$iterations;++$i){
        $action();
    }
    echo $name . ' ' . round(microtime(true)-$time, 6) . "\n";
}

$iterations = 1000000;
$x = array();
$y = range(0, 10000000);
$actions = array(
    "Empty empty()" => function() use($x){
        empty($x);
    },
    "Empty count()" => function() use($x){
        count($x);
    },
    "Full empty()" => function() use($y){
        empty($y);
    },
    "Full count()" => function() use($y){
        count($y);
    },
    ############
    "IF empty empty()" => function() use($x){
        if(empty($x)){ $t=1; }
    },
    "IF empty count()" => function() use($x){
        if(count($x)){ $t=1; }
    },
    "IF full empty()" => function() use($y){
        if(empty($y)){ $t=1; }
    },
    "IF full count()" => function() use($y){
        if(count($y)){ $t=1; }
    },
    ############
    "OR empty empty()" => function() use($x){
        empty($x) OR $t=1;
    },
    "OR empty count()" => function() use($x){
        count($x) OR $t=1;
    },
    "OR full empty()" => function() use($y){
        empty($y) OR $t=1;
    },
    "OR full count()" => function() use($y){
        count($y) OR $t=1;
    },
    ############
    "IF/ELSE empty empty()" => function() use($x){
        if(empty($x)){ $t=1; } else { $t=2; }
    },
    "IF/ELSE empty count()" => function() use($x){
        if(count($x)){ $t=1; } else { $t=2; }
    },
    "IF/ELSE full empty()" => function() use($y){
        if(empty($y)){ $t=1; } else { $t=2; }
    },
    "IF/ELSE full count()" => function() use($y){
        if(count($y)){ $t=1; } else { $t=2; }
    },
    ############
    "( ? : ) empty empty()" => function() use($x){
        $t = (empty($x) ? 1 : 2);
    },
    "( ? : ) empty count()" => function() use($x){
        $t = (count($x) ? 1 : 2);
    },
    "( ? : ) full empty()" => function() use($y){
        $t = (empty($y) ? 1 : 2);
    },
    "( ? : ) full count()" => function() use($y){
        $t = (count($y) ? 1 : 2);
    }
);

foreach($actions as $name => $action){
    benchmark($name, $iterations, $action);
}
//END
```

Since I was doing it I also tried to check the performance doing operations that would normally be associated with count()/empty()

Using PHP 5.4.39:

```
Empty empty() 0.118691
Empty count() 0.218974
Full empty() 0.133747
Full count() 0.216424
IF empty empty() 0.166474
IF empty count() 0.235922
IF full empty() 0.120642
IF full count() 0.248273
OR empty empty() 0.123875
OR empty count() 0.258665
OR full empty() 0.157839
OR full count() 0.224869
IF/ELSE empty empty() 0.167004
IF/ELSE empty count() 0.263351
IF/ELSE full empty() 0.145794
IF/ELSE full count() 0.248425
( ? : ) empty empty() 0.169487
( ? : ) empty count() 0.265701
( ? : ) full empty() 0.149847
( ? : ) full count() 0.252891
```

Using HipHop VM 3.6.1 (dbg)

```
Empty empty() 0.210652
Empty count() 0.212123
Full empty() 0.206016
Full count() 0.204722
IF empty empty() 0.227852
IF empty count() 0.219821
IF full empty() 0.220823
IF full count() 0.221397
OR empty empty() 0.218813
OR empty count() 0.220105
OR full empty() 0.229118
OR full count() 0.221787
IF/ELSE empty empty() 0.221499
IF/ELSE empty count() 0.221274
IF/ELSE full empty() 0.221879
IF/ELSE full count() 0.228737
( ? : ) empty empty() 0.224143
( ? : ) empty count() 0.222459
( ? : ) full empty() 0.221606
( ? : ) full count() 0.231288
```

**Conclusions if you're using PHP:**

1. empty() is much much faster than count() in both scenarios, with an empty and populated array
2. count() performs the same with a full or empty array.
3. Doing a simple IF or just a Boolean operation is the same.
4. IF/ELSE is very slightly more efficient than ( ? : ). Unless you're doing billions of iterations with expressions in the middle it is completely insignificant.

**Conclusions if you're using HHVM:**

1. empty() is a teeny-weeny bit faster than count() but insignificantly so.

   *[ The rest is the same as in PHP ]*

In conclusion of the conclusion, if you just need to know if the array is empty always use empty();

*This was just a curious test simply done without taking many things into account. It is just a proof of concept and might not reflect operations in production.*

Comment: Thanks for the sample testing code.... I just used it and found that `if($x){` is faster than `if(empty($x)){` (only works if you know that `$x` has been declared).

Comment: Your test code is really bad. You adding a lot of additional stuff, like an anonym function call. If I remove and I just run the bare code (for cycle after each other) then I get a huge difference. And I mean in that case the faster if there are no `count` and `empty` calls in the if statement. Then it comes the `empty` and lasts the `count`. But compared to yours in bare case, the empty is ten times faster! Simple array test: 0.104662, empty: 0.177659, count: 1.175125 on PHP 5.6 otherwise your code gives the same result on this version too like your mentioned. Just it's fake results.

Comment: @golddragon007 Their answer is still more useful than your comment, since 1)They're not nasty about it and 2)They actually show their work. Please consider being nicer, since this is a community for helping others, not insulting them.

Comment: I have used `isset($x[0])`, `empty($x)` was faster, but better than `count($x)`

Answer (score 18):

I think it's only personal preference. Some people might say `empty` is faster (e.g. http://jamessocol.com/projects/count_vs_empty.php) while others might say `count` is better since it was originally made for arrays. `empty` is more general and can be applied to other types.

php.net gives the following warning for `count` though :

> count() may return 0 for a variable that isn't set, but it may also return 0 for a variable that has been initialized with an empty array. Use isset() to test if a variable is set.

In other words, if the variable is not set, you will get a notice from PHP saying it's undefined. Therefore, before using `count`, it would be preferable to check the variable with `isset`. This is not necessary with `empty`.

Comment: It's interesting that an argument in favor of `count` is that it was originally made for arrays... yet objects can implement `Countable`, and you can pass scalar values to `count()` and get a valid result.

Comment: *count() **may** return 0 for a variable that isn't set, but it **may** also...*. Official documentation using modal verbs to express its uncertainty :p

Comment: Just a comment on the `isset()` point. If you're worried about notices in PHP you should have already declared your array. If you let PHP dynamically declare your array, you'll get a notice at that point as well.  I think the real point of the warning on php.net is that you shouldn't use `count` to determine if an array has been declared or not as it yields the same result as an empty array would.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there a reason that count should be used instead of empty when determining if an array is empty or not?

There is, when you need to do something on non-empty array knowing it's size:

```
if( 0 < ( $cnt = count($array) ) )
{
 echo "Your array size is: $cnt";
}
else
 echo "Too bad, your array is empty :(";
```

But I wouldn't recommend using count, unless you are 100% sure, that what you are counting is an array. Lately I have been debugging code, where on error function was returning `FALSE` instead of empty array, and what I discovered was:

```
var_dump(count(FALSE));
```

output:

```
int 1
```

So since then I am using `empty` or `if(array() === $array)` to be sure that I have **array** that is empty.

Comment: I know this answer is old. It is worth saying that from 7.2 it will also throw warning (and 1 as reult), and from 8.0 it will throw fatal error.

Answer (score 6):

`count()` seems to work better with array-like interfaces that implement `ArrayAccess/Countable`. `empty()` returns false for these kinds of objects even if they have no elements. Typically these classes will implement the `Countable` interface, so if the question is "Does this collection contain elements?" without making an assumption about the implementation, then `count()` is a better option.

Comment: Do you mean "`empty` returns *false* for these kinds of objects even if they have no elements"?

Comment: Yes. There is no interface to allow a class to define whether it is "empty" or not. And it wouldn't really make sense for there to be one.

Comment: +1 Using `count` would be a more flexible and extensible solution if ever it makes sense for your code to accept a collection implemented a "common" way… IMO that might be the only pertinent criteria for defining if you use `count` or other ways...

Comment: The huge downside of `count()` as of 7.2 is that it can no longer take empty variables.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can cast the variable as a boolean (implicitly or explicitly):

```
if( $value )
{
  // array is not empty
}

if( (bool) $value )
{
  // array is still not empty
}
```

This method does generate an `E_NOTICE` if the variable is not defined, similarly to `count()`.

For more information, see [the PHP Manual page on type comparisons](http://php.net/types.comparisons).

Comment: This is the best way to check, only use `empty()` if you're explicitly trying to avoid triggering an E_NOTICE (which is generally a bad idea, IMO). Blatantly using empty will lead to buggy code.

Answer (score 3):

There is no strong reason to prefer `count($myArray) == 0` over `empty($myArray)`. They have identical semantics. Some might find one more readable than the other. One might perform marginally better than the other but it's not likely to be a significant factor in the vast majority of php applications. For all practical purposes, the choice is a matter of taste.

Comment: What about the "performance" thing? Using explanation of "practial purposes" leads to bad habits. Use `count` when you need count, use `empty` when you need to check if collection is empty. Of course there are edge cases like strings or nulls, but programmer needs to think about his code. You may disagree, you're allowed to.

Comment: some times, with count($myArray) if $myArray is a booleen like a value FALSE, the count is not working (tested on php5.3).

Answer (score 3):

My personal preference is more for coding elegance (in relation to my specific use-case). I agree with Dan McG inasmuch that count() isn't responding with the correct datatype (in this case boolean) for the test in question forcing the developer to write more code to fill an 'if' statement.

Whether this has any significant impact on performance is only debatable for extremely large arrays (which you probably won't have enough memory allocation for anyway in most setups).

Particularly when it comes to PHP's $_POST array, it seems much more "logical" in my opinion to write/see:

```
if ( !empty ( $_POST ) ) {
    // deal with postdata
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this might help someone even though it has already been answered (and debated some what). In my own scenario, I know all my arrays all have 7 elements (checks were made earlier in my code) and I am performing an `array_diff` which of course returns an array of zero when equal.

I had 34 sec for `count` and 17 sec for `empty`. Both give me the same calculations so my code is still fine.

However you can also try the `==` or `===` as in [PHP - Check if two arrays are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal). The best I would say is try `count` vs `empty` vs `== empty array`, then see which gives your own best perfs. In my case `count` was the slowest so **I am using `empty` now**... will be checking `serialize` next

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using empty is a must. For example this code:

```
$myarray = array();

echo "myarray:"; var_dump($myarray); echo "<br>";
echo "case1 count: ".count($myarray)."<br>";
echo "case1 empty: ".empty($myarray)."<br>";

$glob = glob('sdfsdfdsf.txt');

echo "glob:"; var_dump($glob); echo "<br>";
echo "case2 count: ".count($glob)."<br>";
echo "case2 empty: ".empty($glob);
```

If you run this code like this: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g9x-uwi

You get this output:

```
myarray:array(0) { } 
case1 count: 0
case1 empty: 1

glob:bool(false) 
case2 count: 1
case2 empty: 1
```

So if you `count` the empty glob output you get wrong output. You should check for emptiness.

From [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) documentation:

> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty
>   array if no file matched or FALSE on error.
>   Note: On some systems it
>   is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.

Also check this question:
[Why count(false) return 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327508/why-countfalse-return-1)

Answer (score 1):

Since a variable parsed as negative would return `int(1)` with `count()`

I prefer `($array === [] || !$array)` to test for an empty array.

Yes, we should expect an empty array, but we shouldn't expect a good implementation on functions without enforced return types.

Examples with `count()`

```php
var_dump(count(0));
> int(1)
var_dump(count(false));
> int(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I remade my mind guys, thanks.

Ok, there is no difference between the usage of `empty` and `count`. Technically, `count` should be used for arrays, and `empty` could be used for arrays as well as strings. So in most cases, they are interchangeable and if  you see the php docs, you will see the suggestion list of `count` if you are at `empty` and vice versa.