# Insert into Database when ID/name is used multiple times

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this table:

```
foreach( //conditionals ){ 
  <td id="changeStatus">
     <input type="text" name="rcStatus" value=""/>
  </td>
}
```

The `<td>`s are blank, and when I click on each one, the bgcolor of the cell changes, and also the value of `rcStatus`.

I do using this code:

```
<script> 
  $('#table #changeStatus').click(
    function(){
      var cell = $(this);
      state = cell.data('state') || 'first';

    switch(state){
      case 'first':
      cell.addClass('red');
      cell.data('state', 'second');
      this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = "missed";
      break;
      // other cases here 
     }
  });
</script>
```

My problem now is that I need to store the value of `rcStatus` in my database.
What happens is that I am only able to store the most recently set `rcStatus`.
I'm using PHP.

```
foreach( //conditionals ){ 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `details`(ID, Name, Status) VALUES('NULL','$_POST[name]','$_POST[rcStatus]');");
}
```

How can I call each individual variable using `$_POST` even though I'm using the same name/id?

Comment: So you mean in your database, your `ID` and `Name` can be repeated but with different `rcStatus`?

Comment: yes, the value of the `rcStatus` varies depending on the cell clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append a number to the name of the input field to identify each input field, see also [Multiple inputs with same name through POST in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php).

Comment: chose this because the suggested post really helped me out :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use this logic.

```
$i = 1;
foreach( //conditionals ){ 
  <td id="changeStatus">
     <input type="text" name="rcStatus<?php echo $i; ?>" value=""/>
  </td>
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<tr>` to:

```
foreach( //conditionals ){ 
  <td id="changeStatus">
     // giving [] to a name attribute makes it an input array, like @Smutje mentioned
     <input type="text" name="rcStatus[]" value=""/>   
  </td>
}
```

And in your PHP:

```
foreach($_POST[rcStatus] as $key=>$val){ 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `details`(ID, Name, Status) VALUES('NULL','$_POST[name]','$val');");
}
```

A few notes:

1. Please migrate to **mysqli_** functions as **mysql_** is
   **deprecated**
2. You are open to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . For the time being, till you migrate, you can use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to escape `$_POST` values