# Handling dynamically added form data in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, dynamicform

I am working on an web app which contains form page.

```
mandi_detail:[{
        name: String,
        mandi_correspondent_detail:[{
            name:String,
            contact:[Number]
        }]       
    }]
```

this is the model of a schema,  i have made a ui page, in which in **mandi_detail** i can add multiple **mandi** dynamically .

In each  **mandi**, we have **name** and **mandi_correspondent_detail**. we can add multiple **mandi_correspondent_detail** dynamically.

Each **mandi_correspondent_detail**  consist name and contact number and we can add multiple numbers by number field dynamically.

how to get the posted data in controller so that i am able to insert it in schema in mongodb.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Your view should be build according to your controller's data. This way you'll use `two way binding` and everything will be up to date

Example:

In your `controller`

```
 $scope.myData=[];

 $scope.pushNew= function(){

    // build your newMandy object from the form existing in html
    // validate your form

    var newMandy={
      name: String,
      mandi_correspondent_detail:[{
         name:String,
         contact:[Number]
      }]       
    }

    $scope.myData.push(newMandy);
 }
```

In your `view`

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData">
    // your html structure here
</div>

// form for adding new mandy
<button ng-click="pushNew()">Add mandy details</button>
```

This way you can use `myData` array to store everything in your `DB`

Comment: how to differ..when i add another mandi then their model name become same hence data replicated ....how to name model so that they can accessed appropriately

Comment: they don't need same name.. you have a ng-repeat there and each `data in myData` has a different scope. And if you want to modify one `data from myData`  send it as a parameter to a function. Post your code if you have other problems