# jQuery live search for many input (array) fields

Tags: jquery, arrays, livesearch

I try to do a jQuery live search for many input fields.
With only 1 input field (without array) it's working all great,
but with many search fields with array there is just happening nothing.
(The *livesearch.php* file is for now only saying "echo 'test';")

I hope you can help me.

Thanks for answer.
But it still doesn't work.
I just don't understand why the ajax-part doesn't work.
I edited my code to the following:

```
    <html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
      <div id="main">

        First search field:<br>
        <input type="text" name="search[]" class="search" autocomplete="off">
        <div></div>

        Second search field:<br>
        <input type="text" name="search[]" class="search" autocomplete="off">
        <div></div>

      </div>

      <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {  

          $('.search').on("keyup", function(e) {

            var search_string = $(this).val();

            // Do Search
            if (search_string == '') {
              $(this).next().fadeOut();
            }else{
              $(this).next().fadeIn();

              //$(this).next().html("hallo"); //THIS WORKS!!!


              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./livesearch.php",
                data: { query: search_string },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                  $(this).next().html(data); //THIS DOESN'T WORK!!!
                }
              });

            };
          });

        });

      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason of your problem is simple, this happens because , this pointer **this** is not showing to the same element as in the beginning.

At first the **this**,  points to the input element, that is why it works correct,  **but inside the $.ajax request , it means the **function success**  itself.**

in order to work correct assign **this** to a new variable and use **that** variable inside the **success function**.

```
var myInputElmnt = $(this);//assign this to temp variable
.....
$(myInputElmnt).next().html(data); //it works because it shows to your input element
```

see my fixes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

          $('.search').on("keyup", function(e) {

            var search_string = $(this).val();

            var myInputElmnt = $(this);//assign this to temp variable

            // Do Search
            if (search_string == '') {
              $(this).next().fadeOut();
            }else{
              $(this).next().fadeIn();

              $(myInputElmnt).next().html("hallo"); //THIS WORKS ALSO


              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./livesearch.php",
                data: { query: search_string },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){

                  $(myInputElmnt).next().html(data); //it works because it shows to your input element
                }
              });

            };
          });

        });
```

this should make the trick,
hope helps good luck.

Comment: omg :D thanks for the solution and the great explanation! it works great!

Answer (score 0):

i recommend this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php) for using inputs with same names.
you cannot use IDs twice. they should be unique!

try folloing:

```
<input type="text" name="search[]" class="search" id="search1" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="search[]" class="search" id="search2" autocomplete="off">
```

and use simple selectors for simple reading js:

```
$('.search').on('keyup', ...
```

ul seems always after **.search** so you could use in scope of current .search

```
$(this).next() // jQuery object of ul
```