# Multiple checkboxes with one name (no jquery!)

Tags: html, forms, codeigniter, post, checkbox

I have a following list of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week" value="1">Monday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week" value="2">Tuesday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week" value="3">Wednessday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week" value="4">Thursday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week" value="5">Friday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week" value="6">Saturday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week" value="7">Sunday
```

After user submits the full form, I receive it in another file:

```
$week_days = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id, $_POST['day_of_week'])
```

But then $week_days only contains the value of the last checked checkbox, not all of them. How can I receive all the values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple inputs with same name through POST in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name should be an array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week[]" value="1">Monday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week[]" value="2">Tuesday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week[]" value="3">Wednessday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week[]" value="4">Thursday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week[]" value="5">Friday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week[]" value="6">Saturday
<input type="checkbox" name="day_of_week[]" value="7">Sunday
```

Hope this helps.

---

For your second error, mysqli_real_escape_string accepts second parameter as string and you are passing array. Please check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

Please use for loop to solve that error.

Comment: Produces a following error: Message: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: Solved it like this: `$week_days = '';`
      `for($i=0;$i<7;++$i){
            $week_days .= (isset($_POST['day_of_week'][$i])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,$_POST['day_of_week'][$i]) : '';}`

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. You need to use loop to solve it.