# Multiple inputs with same name through POST in bootstrap?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap

[Multiple inputs with same name through POST in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php)

I've looked at this and I was hoping I could get something similar with python and bootstrap but it just shows Nonetype with "key[]" or the last value if I just use "key".

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" tal:repeat="a keys">
        <input type="checkbox" name="key[]" value="${a.id}">${a.name}
    </label>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What "Python" are you using here? Python is not PHP, it is not a web language in itself, so you will need to explain what kind of framework you are using on the back end and show the code.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 with pyramid, and currently just printing to the console to see what's there.