# only get the value of last checkbox from forum POST

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the POST data from my form the problem I'm having is it only displays the last make item submitted? What am I doing wrong? I have tried serval things to get it to work and all with no luck!

Refine.php

```
   sort($make);
   foreach($make as $key => $value):
       if($value != '')
      {
        echo '
          <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="make" value="'.$value.'" id="'.$value.'">
            '.ucfirst(strtolower($value)).'</label>
          <br>';
       }
    endforeach;
```

Browse.php

```
foreach($_POST['make'] as $item){
echo $item;

}
```

Comment: modify name to `name="make[]"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple inputs with same name through POST in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php)

Comment: 3 AM is way to late to be coding that worked thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

kotapeter nailed it!

```
sort($make);
   foreach($make as $key => $value):
       if($value != '')
      {
        echo '
          <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="make[]" value="'.$value.'" id="'.$value.'">
            '.ucfirst(strtolower($value)).'</label>
          <br>';
       }
    endforeach;
```