# How to submit an array using HTML and Ajax and send it to PHP as array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to submit some of my HTML inputs as an array, and use it in PHP, but the other inputs are being passed to PHP by Ajax (using jQuery). So I need to get the value of the inputs and send them to a PHP file by Ajax. My inputs are like these:

```
<input value="..." type="hidden" name="something[]" />
<input value="..." type="hidden" name="something[]" />
<input value="..." type="hidden" name="something[]" />
```

I have never used this way to submit an array and just saw it. I will be thankful if someone explains this way (`name="something[]"`).

Comment: where is the `ajax` you have tried?

Comment: similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php
Post code example for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you need to `POST`that payload:**

Use the function `$.serialize()`

```
var payload = $('[name="somthing[]"]').serialize();
console.log(payload);

$.post( URL, payload);
```

**Or you can use the function `.ajax()`:**

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: URL,
  data: payload
});
```

## Resource

- [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
- [`$.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @DanielGale I didn't understand.