# serialize() multiple rows in table with same name and send to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, pdo

I'd like to serialzie multiple rows in my table using `serialize()` to update my database. The form data looks like this:

```
f_name=tom&l_name=riddle=&f_name=albus&l_name=dumbledore
```

If I send this data to php with `$.post('file.php', formData, function(result)` and log the returned result I can only see the last entry (f_name=albus&l_name=dumbledore). How can I send multiple rows with the same input fields to the php file?

Comment: There are too many tags with no supportive code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple inputs with same name through POST in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your inputs array-style names:

```
<input name="f_name[]" type="text">
<input name="l_name[]" type="text">
```

Then the correspoding `$_POST` variables will be arrays, with an element for each row. The form data will look like

```
f_name[]=tom&l_name[]=riddle=&f_name[]=albus&l_name[]=dumbledore
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I can loop through $_POST to update the datebase?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual technique.

Comment: alright, and how do I know how many loops it needs? Should I count using `count($_POST['f_name'])`? So its no problem if I update the database x times after each other?

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['fname'] as $i => $fname)`

Comment: Then you can use `$lname = $_POST['l_name'][$i];`

Comment: This is no different from looping over any other array, which should be familiar territory.

Comment: I use `bindParam` so I just loop through a for loop with a foreach loop for binding? Is this okay? Can we move this dicussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214453/discussion-between-barmar-and-mr-potter).