# My array is not empty but empty() claims it is

Tags: php

I've var dumped my array:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(72) "
1
" [1]=> string(57) "
2
" [2]=> string(63) "
›
" [3]=> string(63) "
»
" }
```

When I check:

```
empty($myArray);
```

It always says true. Why is this?

Comment: Can you please show a bit more context? For instance, your debugging code.

Comment: then use count() to check the array is empty or not

Comment: Could you put exact code you use for creating array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
count($myArray) == 0
```

instead

Answer (score -1):

- empty() function returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.
- The following things are considered to be empty, and return value would be true:
- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)

Comment: How does it help in this case? We all see array is not empty.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively,you can check with count() function like this:-

```
if((count($myArray) < 1) || (count($myArray)) === 0){
    echo 'Array is empty';
}else{
  echo 'There is Data in Array';
}
```

Comment: Not true. `$myArray` is variable, isn't it? Empty function works also for arrays: `The following things are considered to be empty: array() (an empty array)`

Comment: I didn't say you can't use it. but the empty function works some times delivers not the expected result. if used count(), with arrays that is more reliable. What i have wrote is the exact explanation on the php site. If you you are more knowledgeable in it. prove me wrong.

Comment: You can look for example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216110/checking-for-empty-arrays-count-vs-empty?rq=1