# Is this the correct way of checking empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, comparison

I want to check if array is empty or not, i wrote few lines of code for it

```
if(array() == $myArray){
   echo "Array";
}
```

or

```
if(array() === $myArray){
   echo "Array";
}
```

I'm confused which one to use, as the second condition also checks type. But i think in the case of array we don't need to check their type. 
Please anybody can suggest me which one to use.

Comment: Use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for empty arrays: count vs empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216110/checking-for-empty-arrays-count-vs-empty)

Answer (score 3):

you can check it by using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function like below

```
<?php   
    if(empty($myArray)) {
      //condition
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (! count($myArray)) {
    // array is empty
}
```

Let php do its thing and check for booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Use `empty`:

```
if (empty($myArray)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php

$array = array();
if(empty($array))
{
 echo "empty";
} else
{
echo "some thing!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to check first whether it is array or not and then it is empty or not. I always use like this because whenever I check only empty condition somewhere I don't get the expected result

```
if( is_array($myArray) and !empty($myArray) ){
    .....
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 

if(empty($yourarry)){

}
```

> OR

```
if(isset($yourarry)){


}
```

> OR

```
if(count($yourarry)==0){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

- Use `count==0` if your *array* could also be an object implementing [Countable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php)
- Use `empty` otherwise

`array() == $myArray` is unreadable, you should avoid it. You can [see the difference between count and empty here](https://3v4l.org/JqcaY).