# PHP: What is the complexity [i.e O(1),O(n)] of the function 'count'?

Tags: php

What is the Big-O time complexity of the [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function for arrays?

Example

```
$x = array(1,2,3);
echo count($x); // how many operation does it takes to count the elements 
                // of the array? is it 3, or is it 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is PHP's count() function O(1) or O(n) for arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835241/is-phps-count-function-o1-or-on-for-arrays)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$ time php -r '$a=range(1,1000000); $b=0; for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) $b=count($a);'
real    0m0.458s
$ time php -r '$a=range(1,1000000); $a=array(1); $b=0; for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) $b=count($a);'
real    0m0.457s
```

Seems pretty O(1) to me.

Tested PHP version: `PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 15 2010 14:00:18)`

Answer (score 20):

Arrays have O(1) size- that is, their size is stored somewhere. The language updates the count on insertion/deletion.