# Undefined offset with count()

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, count

I have an array `$MyArray` which has some elements which are also array (lets call them subarrays). I want to know how many elements the subarray with the most elements has. The problem is, that I don't know if the index exists:

```
 max(
     @count($MyArray[$i*7]), 
     @count($MyArray[$i*7+1]), 
     @count($MyArray[$i*7+2]),         
     @count($MyArray[$i*7+3]),
     @count($MyArray[$i*7+4]),
     @count($MyArray[$i*7+5]),
     @count($MyArray[$i*7+6])
 );
```

Struckture of `$MyArray`:

```
Array(
  12 => array ( 
        0 => array ( 0 => 0, 1 => 1, ), 
        1 => array ( 0 => 13, 1 => 1, ), 
        2 => array ( 0 => 15, 1 => 1, ), 
        3 => array ( 0 => 20, 1 => 1, ), 
        4 => array ( 0 => 69, 1 => 1, ) 
  ),
  5 => array ( 
        0 => array ( 0 => 55, 1 => 1, ), 
        1 => array ( 0 => 32, 1 => 1, ), 
        2 => array ( 0 => 12, 1 => 1, ), 
        3 => array ( 0 => 21, 1 => 5, ) 
  ),
  ....
)
```

Can this be done better (faster)?

edit: I know `foreach` and I don't want to loop over every element in this array. I just want an interval of it. `@` is used, because I don't know if `$MyArray[$i*7 + x]` is `Null` or an `array`.

`$i` is a element of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] (sometimes also 5)

Comment: so, basically you have one array with many subarrays, and the goal is to get the subarray with the highest number of element and count it's total elements?

Comment: @kjy112, goal is to just count that subarray's elements, not even get that subarray.

Comment: PHP error suppression, `@`, when overused is the devil

Comment: I don't get how most the answers use `foreach` and completely ignore the `$i*7+y` bit, especially since `$MyArray` structure is unknown...

Comment: @netcoder: I upvoted your answer for doing that, but I don't feel the question is fully clear yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array();
for ($j=0;$j<=6;$j++) {
   if (isset($MyArray[$i*7+$j])) $arr[] = count($MyArray[$i*7+$j]);
}
$result = max($arr);
```

I don't know exactly what `$i` refers to though...

Comment: Hi netcoder,
thanks for your script. It seems like it is the fastest (see http://martin-thoma.blogspot.com/2011/01/benchmarking-php.html). I thought using more functions (`isset` + `count`) would take more time than simply surpressing the warnings with `@` and don't using `isset`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$biggest = 0;
foreach ($MyArray as $value) {
    if ($biggest < count($value)) {
        $biggest = count($value);
    }
}
```

I see, you want the size of the biggest array in the array, correct?

Comment: I'd upvote you, but you are unnecessarily calling `count` twice

Comment: @brain_d: I'm pretty sure that's not a concern.  `count()` just gets the size, it doesn't actually _count_ them.  And storing it into an array just creates a variable, which uses up processing.  Plus, caching is not necessary to convey the concept.  Thanks for the observation though.

Comment: +1 I was not aware it was O(1). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566314/php-what-is-the-complexity-i-e-o1-on-of-the-function-count

Answer (score 3):

Simple and old school approach:

```
<?php

$max = -1;
foreach($MyArray as $subarray)
{
    $items = count($subarray);
    if($items > $max)
         $max = $items;
}

echo $max;
?>
```

This works best since you only want to know **how many elements** the subarray with the most elements has.

Answer (score 3):

```
$max = 0;
foreach ($MyArray as $value) {
    $max = max($max,count($value));
}
```

Comment: `$max = $MyArray ? max(array_map('count', $MyArray)) : 0;` is even better IMO :-)

Comment: @user576875: 8O that's awesome.  I didn't know you could pass an array to `max`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// get the interesting part of the array
$chunk = array_intersect_key($input_array, array_flip(range($i*7, $i*7+6))); 
// max(count)
$max = $chunk ? max(array_map('count', $chunk)) : 0;
```

Comment: Well, this wasn't exactly right, but almost. range gives values, but I need keys:

    $chunk = array_intersect_key($MyArray, array($i*7=>1, $i*7+1=>2, $i*7+2=>3, $i*7+3=>4, $i*7+4=>5, $i*7+5=>6)); 
    if(count($chunk) > 0){$max = max(array_map('count', $chunk));}
    else {$max = 0;}

Comment: ah you are right; then `$chunk = array_intersect_key($input_array, array_flip(range($i*7, $i*7+6)));
$max = $chunk ? max(array_map('count', $chunk)) : 0;`