# Keeping a counter variable vs using count() at every iteration in PHP

Tags: php, optimization, micro-optimization

In an infinite loop, i want to break out based on number of elements in an array. Say:

```
$myarr = array();

While (True){
    //... do something that modifies $myarr ...
    if (count($myarr) > 100000) { break; }
}
```

The problem is, every time i try to code this way, thoughts of micro-optimization creeps in my mind(blame me). I tell myself: why not just use a variable to keep track of the number of elements in the array? Like this:

```
$myarr = array();
$n_myarr = 0;

while (True){
    // ... do something that modifies $myarr
    if ( ... elements added ... )
        { $n_myarr += $n_elements_added; }

    else if ( ... elements removed ... )
        { $n_myarr -= $n_elements_removed; }

    if ($n_myarr > 1000000) { break; }
}
```

As far as I understand, how count() performs is completely dependent on underlying implementation of count() and array. I always prefer to write in simpler ways, if i can, like the 1st code snippet. Can anyone enlighten me on this subject? Especially, how does count() work under the hood?

Thank you.

-Titon

Answer (score 2):

After writing a little benchmark script, i think i've found my answer. Here's the code of the script:

```
<?php

$n_iteration = 1e7;

$test_sizes = array(
    1e2, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6, 2e6, 3e6, 4e6, 5e6
);

foreach ($test_sizes as $test_size){
    $test_array = range(1, $test_size);

    $start_time = microtime(true);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n_iteration; $i++)
        { $x = count($test_array); }

    $end_time = microtime(true);
    $interval = $end_time - $start_time;
    printf(
        "Iterations: %d, Size: %8.d,"
        ." Total time: %6.3f sec, Avg. time: %1.3e sec\n",
        $n_iteration, $test_size, $interval, $interval/$n_iteration);

}
```

Running the script in my machine with "PHP 5.4.4-2 (cli) (built: Jun 19 2012 07:38:55)" produces the following output:

```
Iterations: 10000000, Size:      100, Total time:  3.548 sec, Avg. time: 3.548e-7 sec
Iterations: 10000000, Size:     1000, Total time:  3.368 sec, Avg. time: 3.368e-7 sec
Iterations: 10000000, Size:    10000, Total time:  3.549 sec, Avg. time: 3.549e-7 sec
Iterations: 10000000, Size:   100000, Total time:  3.407 sec, Avg. time: 3.407e-7 sec
Iterations: 10000000, Size:  1000000, Total time:  4.557 sec, Avg. time: 4.557e-7 sec
Iterations: 10000000, Size:  2000000, Total time:  3.263 sec, Avg. time: 3.263e-7 sec
Iterations: 10000000, Size:  3000000, Total time:  3.574 sec, Avg. time: 3.574e-7 sec
Iterations: 10000000, Size:  4000000, Total time:  4.047 sec, Avg. time: 4.047e-7 sec
Iterations: 10000000, Size:  5000000, Total time:  3.628 sec, Avg. time: 3.628e-7 sec
```

As we can see, avg. time spent inside a single count() is approximately constant, around 0.4 microsecond, irrespective of the size of the array.

**Conclusion:**

PHP itself keeps track of the number of elements in an array in an efficient way(count() has O(1) runtime cost). No need to use extra variables for efficiency.

***count() is healthy for both syntactical clarity and efficiency.***

Answer (score 2):

You should cache the result of `count()`, it's probably not going to make a *huge* difference, but it's still an easy optimization. Calling count vs caching the result is approximately 4 times slower.

> Code

```
$array = range(0,100000);

for($x = 100; $x <= 1000000; $x += 100) {

    $countResults = [];
    $staticResults = [];

    for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {

        $start = microtime(true);
        for($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j++) {}
        $end = microtime(true);

        $countResults[] = $end-$start;

        $start = microtime(true);
        $size = count($array);
        for($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++) {}
        $end = microtime(true);

        $staticResults[] = $end-$start;

    }

    $countSum = array_sum($countResults);

    echo sprintf(
         "Count  - Iterations: %d; Total Time: %05.6f; Avg time: %05.6f\n",
         $x,
         $countSum,
         $countSum/$x
     );

    $staticSum = array_sum($staticResults);

    echo sprintf(
         "Static - Iterations: %d; Total Time: %05.6f; Avg time: %05.6f\n",
         $x,
         $staticSum,
         $staticSum/$x
     );

}
```

> Results:

```
Count  - Iterations: 100; Total Time: 0.962752; Avg time: 0.009628
Static - Iterations: 100; Total Time: 0.253768; Avg time: 0.002538
Count  - Iterations: 200; Total Time: 2.258045; Avg time: 0.011290
Static - Iterations: 200; Total Time: 0.579273; Avg time: 0.002896
Count  - Iterations: 300; Total Time: 2.907984; Avg time: 0.009693
Static - Iterations: 300; Total Time: 0.786796; Avg time: 0.002623
Count  - Iterations: 400; Total Time: 3.756074; Avg time: 0.009390
Static - Iterations: 400; Total Time: 1.004253; Avg time: 0.002511
Count  - Iterations: 500; Total Time: 5.086776; Avg time: 0.010174
Static - Iterations: 500; Total Time: 1.363288; Avg time: 0.002727
Count  - Iterations: 600; Total Time: 6.626471; Avg time: 0.011044
Static - Iterations: 600; Total Time: 1.793517; Avg time: 0.002989
Count  - Iterations: 700; Total Time: 6.780818; Avg time: 0.009687
Static - Iterations: 700; Total Time: 1.816578; Avg time: 0.002595
Count  - Iterations: 800; Total Time: 7.640220; Avg time: 0.009550
Static - Iterations: 800; Total Time: 2.026010; Avg time: 0.002533
Count  - Iterations: 900; Total Time: 8.436923; Avg time: 0.009374
Static - Iterations: 900; Total Time: 2.237418; Avg time: 0.002486
Count  - Iterations: 1000; Total Time: 9.483782; Avg time: 0.009484
Static - Iterations: 1000; Total Time: 2.520293; Avg time: 0.002520
Count  - Iterations: 1100; Total Time: 10.492371; Avg time: 0.009539
Static - Iterations: 1100; Total Time: 2.803949; Avg time: 0.002549
Count  - Iterations: 1200; Total Time: 11.305185; Avg time: 0.009421
Static - Iterations: 1200; Total Time: 3.027705; Avg time: 0.002523
Count  - Iterations: 1300; Total Time: 12.249071; Avg time: 0.009422
Static - Iterations: 1300; Total Time: 3.265644; Avg time: 0.002512
Count  - Iterations: 1400; Total Time: 13.166538; Avg time: 0.009405
Static - Iterations: 1400; Total Time: 3.499845; Avg time: 0.002500
Count  - Iterations: 1500; Total Time: 14.204276; Avg time: 0.009470
Static - Iterations: 1500; Total Time: 3.776997; Avg time: 0.002518
Count  - Iterations: 1600; Total Time: 15.280157; Avg time: 0.009550
Static - Iterations: 1600; Total Time: 4.076611; Avg time: 0.002548
Count  - Iterations: 1700; Total Time: 15.938380; Avg time: 0.009376
Static - Iterations: 1700; Total Time: 4.246082; Avg time: 0.002498
Count  - Iterations: 1800; Total Time: 16.967943; Avg time: 0.009427
Static - Iterations: 1800; Total Time: 4.493304; Avg time: 0.002496
Count  - Iterations: 1900; Total Time: 17.870854; Avg time: 0.009406
Static - Iterations: 1900; Total Time: 4.749316; Avg time: 0.002500
Count  - Iterations: 2000; Total Time: 18.900052; Avg time: 0.009450
Static - Iterations: 2000; Total Time: 5.038069; Avg time: 0.002519
Count  - Iterations: 2100; Total Time: 20.487390; Avg time: 0.009756
Static - Iterations: 2100; Total Time: 5.480530; Avg time: 0.002610
Count  - Iterations: 2200; Total Time: 21.328690; Avg time: 0.009695
Static - Iterations: 2200; Total Time: 5.671044; Avg time: 0.002578
Count  - Iterations: 2300; Total Time: 22.270163; Avg time: 0.009683
Static - Iterations: 2300; Total Time: 5.906530; Avg time: 0.002568
Count  - Iterations: 2400; Total Time: 23.392992; Avg time: 0.009747
Static - Iterations: 2400; Total Time: 6.225149; Avg time: 0.002594
Count  - Iterations: 2500; Total Time: 24.346405; Avg time: 0.009739
Static - Iterations: 2500; Total Time: 6.494287; Avg time: 0.002598
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking faster processing the second code will perform faster, because you're not using the function and if you look for the count function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php you can see that it's implemented from a class and as we all know OOP is slower than the procedural code.

Comment: You have a point. But I'm not concerned if the cumulative time spent in count() slows the code slightly due to OOP implementation, rather:

It is wise to call count() on an array with millions of elements? What is the "big O performance characteristics" of count() ?

Comment: OOP is 5 to 10% slower than procedural code. Adding and subtracting from a variable is faster than calling a function every time you enter the loop.I think that it's wise to use count only once - in the initialization of the variable, that shows you the number of the elements.

Comment: "you can see that it's implemented from a class"? Array is not a class in PHP. The implementation is pure C.

Comment: @duskwuff If you had read the description of the function in php.net you would have read the following "The interface has exactly one method, Countable::count(), which returns the return value for the count() function." So yeah it's implented from a class.

Comment: That's only used when `count()` is used on objects which are instances of SPL classes. Array is not an object; it's a primitive type.