# Efficient loops in PHP

Tags: php, performance, function, for-loop

What is more efficient for the following loop operation in PHP:

```
$k = count($array);
for ($i = 0;  $i < $k; $i++)
{
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

Or

```
for ($i = 0;  $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

I know that in JavaScript there is something like this possible and more efficient:

```
for (i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++)
{
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: This question is just academic, in practice you won't notice a difference, especially if you are not changing the size of the array while iterating.

Comment: Your first example is the best way to do a for loop since you've cached the value of `$k`, in your second example you're recounting after every iteration.

Comment: Also, count is O(1): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835241/phps-count-o1-or-on-for-arrays

Comment: You can use the same syntax in PHP as well: `for ($i = 0, $j = count($array);  $i < $j; $i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case your first example is faster, simply because to evaluate the condition `$i < count($array)` PHP will execute `count()` after every loop. So following that logic it would be faster to use a variable in your condition, rather than a function.

The more practical approach would be to use foreach() as mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

This one is more efficient than 2nd one

```
<?php 
$k = count($array);
for($i = 0;  $i < $k; $i++)
{
    echo $array[$i];
}
?>
```

thanks.

Comment: Some explanation as to why it is more efficient would help....

Comment: because when you debug the code then you can get idea that each time system need to count the total number of element from the array so better you use the one variable and pass the total number of array's element so loop no need to count array element each time...

Answer (score 2):

**The first one** is more efficient, the second one is calling the function `count()` each iteration.

Comment: That is not true, see my answer for results of test

Comment: You have one nested loop and calls `count()` each iteration of the 1st loop. More work than the second :/

Comment: Yes, sorry i had a few errors in there @naoink - i have fixed them now. I will remove downvote.

Comment: No problem, errors are human :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `foreach` in this context.

From the [`PHP Docs`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)..

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.

#### Why `foreach` is efficient in this case ?

- Definitely faster since you won't be calling a `count()` for determining the length of the array as you did above.
- You can even access the keys of the arrays.

Comment: Also see this Stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php

Comment: Ease of use often comes with additional computations behind the curtain.

Answer (score 1):

Lets test and see.

```
 $array = array();
 $array = array_pad($array, 1000, 0);
 $iters = 1e4;

 $tic = microtime(true);
 for ($jj = 0; $jj < $iters; $jj++) {
   $k = count($array);
   for($i = 0;  $i < $k; $i++) {
       $vv = $array[$i];
   }
 }
 $toc = microtime(true);
 $time = $toc - $tic;
 echo "Time for external \$k..: $time\n";


 $tic = microtime(true);
 for ($jj = 0; $jj < $iters; $jj++) {
   for($i = 0;  $i < count($array); $i++) {
       $vv = $array[$i];
   }
 }
 $toc = microtime(true);
 $time = $toc - $tic;
 echo "Time for count(\$k)....: $time\n";



 $tic = microtime(true);
 for ($jj = 0; $jj < $iters; $jj++) {
   foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
       $vv = $array[$i];
   }
 }
 $toc = microtime(true);
 $time = $toc - $tic;
 echo "Time foreach..........: $time\n";
```

Results:

```
 Time for external $k..: 5.2356481552124
 Time for count($k)....: 35.91916513443
 Time foreach..........: 4.0548861026764
```

Comment: Benchmarking is the best possible answer to such questions, true, but is that 4.91 seconds number correct? I highly doubt it

Comment: 4 seconds? impossible.

Comment: Lol are you discarding the `E-10` stuff thinking its not needed? That's part of the number and it makes hell a lot of a difference

Comment: These numbers are grossly misrepresenting the actual time and making your good answer look bad

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky how would you improve it?

Comment: I can not unfortunately do so, the numbers you have provided are from your own machine and benchmark results differ from one machine to another.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would be more efficient

```
for ($i = 0;  $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

as no extra variable is defined to store the count of array requiring less memory space

Comment: Quote James: "Your first example is the best way to do a for loop since you've cached the value of $k, in your second example you're recounting after every iteration"

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

    foreach ($yourArayValue as $test=>$value)
      {
      echo $test;
      }
?>
```

foreach() is batter

Comment: what the reason of down-vote :(

Comment: I didn't downvote but the reasons look obvious, The suggestion you gave is not even the one that was asked. The original question didn't ask for a foreach and everyone is answering that, secondly just saying something is better doesn't make it better. You have to give reasons for your claim.