# Filtering an array - using two other arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Structure `$data->products` (There are about 10,000 products). Each of the products has parameters.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 440
            [name] => Product1
            [parameters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Parameter1
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [name] => ValueParameter1
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Parameter2
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                            [name] => ValueParameter2
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Parameter3
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [name] => ValueParameter3
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                    [3] => .........
                        ...
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => Product2
            [parameters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Parameter2
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                            [name] => ValueParameter2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Parameter3
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [name] => ValueParameter3
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 35
                            [name] => Parameter35
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 64
                                            [name] => ValueParameter35
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                    [3] => .........
                        ...

                )

        )
    [2] => ....
    .....
```

**What do I want to get?**

- `$data->products` is an array to be filtered on.
- `$filterContains` parameters ID array - filtering products that contain parameters with given IDs.
- `$filterExclude` parameters ID array - filtering products excluding the specified IDs.

I want to get an array of products taking into account the IDs of the parameters, which are specified in the filter arrays (`$filterContains` & `$filterExclude`).

Products that contain parameters,`$filterContains`, excluding parameters from `$filterExclude`.

**Code:**

```
function getFilteredData($data, array $filterContains = [], array $filterExclude = []): array
{
    $result = [];
    $keyCount = count($filterContains);
    foreach ($data->products as $product) {
        if (isset($product['parameters'])) {
            $match = 0;
            $product['parameters'] = array_values($product['parameters']);
            foreach ($product['parameters'] as $parameter) {
                foreach ($filterContains as $value) {
                    if ($parameter['id'] == $value && !in_array($parameter['id'], $filterExclude)) {
                        $match++;
                    }
                }
                if ($match == $keyCount) {
                    $result[] = $product;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $unique_array = [];
    foreach ($result as $element) {
        $hash = $element['id'];
        $unique_array[$hash] = $element;
    }
    $result = array_values($unique_array);
    return $result;
}
```

It seems to me only works for products that contain the given parameters, but it doesn't exclude the parameters given in `$filterExclude`.

I hope I have described the problem quite clearly. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems

I believe that the implementation is overcomplicated, making the code harder to follow and slower than needed. For instance:

- You don't need to filter unique products.
- You don't need to call `array_values`.
- If you found a parameter ID in `$filterExclude`, you don't need to keep checking if there's a match.

**But why is not working?**

The code checks if there isn't an ID in `$filterExclude` only when it's in `$filterContains`:

[image: diagram showing the condition is only checking IDs in $filterContains]

So, it only seems to work when the function when the IDs in `$filterExclude` also exist in `$filterContains`, for instance:

```php
getFilteredData($data, [1, 2], [1]);
```

## Simpler solution

```php
function array_some(array $array, callable $function): bool
{
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($function($item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function getFilteredData($data, array $filterContains = [], array $filterExclude = []): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data->products as $product) {
        if (
            isset($product['parameters'])
            && !array_some($product['parameters'], function ($parameter) use ($filterExclude) { return in_array($parameter['id'], $filterExclude); })
            && array_some($product['parameters'], function ($parameter) use ($filterContains) { return in_array($parameter['id'], $filterContains); })
        ) {
            $result []= $product;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Or this one, if you want each product having all the parameters IDs from `$filterContains`:

```php
function getFilteredData($data, array $filterContains = [], array $filterExclude = []): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data->products as $product) {
        if (!isset($product['parameters'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $ids = array_map(function ($parameter) { return $parameter['id']; }, $product['parameters']);
        if (
            !array_some($ids, function ($id) use ($filterExclude) { return in_array($id, $filterExclude); })
            && !array_some($filterContains, function ($id) use ($ids) { return !in_array($id, $ids); })
        ) {
            $result []= $product;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I think PHP doesn't have functions like `array_some` and `array_all`.
Also, anonymous functions are ugly (they're better in JavaScript), especially when we need `use`. PHP has [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) since PHP 7.4, though.

## Maybe with better performance

Calling `array_some` twice implies transversing the array twice.
We can check if each parameter ID is in `$filterContains` and it's not in `$filterExclude` while transversing the array once.

You don't need to count the parameters to check if the conditions are matched. Use a flag (a boolean) to check if a parameter ID in `$filterContains` was found. If a parameter ID is in `$filterExclude`, set that flag to `false` and break the loop. If that flag is true, there's a match.

Also, `array_in` is transversing the filters several times. That is not required when a [set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php) is used. The class `Ds\Set` might not be available, but with `array_flip` you get an associative array and used it as a set with `is_set`. But building the associative array and generating hashes to access might be slower than using `array_in` if there are few products and the filters have few items.

```php
function getFilteredData($data, array $filterContains = [], array $filterExclude = []): array
{
    $result = [];
    $filterContainsSet = array_flip($filterContains);
    $filterExcludeSet = array_flip($filterExclude);
    foreach ($data->products as $product) {
        if (!isset($product['parameters'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $found = false;
        foreach ($product['parameters'] as $parameter) {
            $id = $parameter['id'];
            if (isset($filterExcludeSet[$id])) {
                $found = false;
                break;
            } elseif (isset($filterContainsSet[$id])) {
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if ($found) {
            $result []= $product;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Note that, despite the nested loop, there are only two loops in that function.

If you want each product having all the parameters IDs in `$filterContains`:

```php
function getFilteredData($data, array $filterContains = [], array $filterExclude = []): array
{
    $result = [];
    $filterContainsSet = array_flip($filterContains);
    $filterExcludeSet = array_flip($filterExclude);
    foreach ($data->products as $product) {
        if (!isset($product['parameters'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $found = [];
        foreach ($product['parameters'] as $parameter) {
            $id = $parameter['id'];
            if (isset($filterExcludeSet[$id])) {
                $found = [];
                break;
            } elseif (isset($filterContainsSet[$id])) {
                $found[$id] = true;
            }
        }
        if (count($found) >= count($filterContains)) {
            $result []= $product;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Note: [`count` reuses a cached integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835241/is-phps-count-function-o1-or-on-for-arrays).

If you rather have an implementation that does not have `count`:

```php
function getFilteredData($data, array $filterContains = [], array $filterExclude = []): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data->products as $product) {
        if (!isset($product['parameters'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $idSet = array_flip(array_map(function($parameter) { return $parameter['id']; }, $product['parameters']));
        if (
            !array_some($filterExclude, function($id) use ($idSet) { return isset($idSet[$id]); })
            && !array_some($filterContains, function($id) use ($idSet) { return !isset($idSet[$id]); })
        ) {
            $result []= $product;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```