# how to get data from an array inside a recursive array?

Tags: php

Say I create a recursive array with this code:

```
$digits = 0;
$tens = 0;
$hundreds = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    $myArray[$hundreds][$tens][$digits] = $i;

    $digits++;
    if($digits > 9)
    {
        $digits = 0;
        $tens++;
    }

    if($tens > 9)
    {
        $tens = 0;
        $hundreds++;
    }
}
```

how could I echo out all the data fromt the `'tens array' == 2`?

To be clear, I'd be looking for these results:

```
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

since im using base 10, I could just do this:

```
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
  echo $myArray[0][2][$i]
}
```

but what if i have no idea how many elements are in the digits array?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($myArray[0][2] as $v) {
 echo $v."<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: with php everything is simple (almost)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$tensArr =  $myArray[0][2];
for($i= 0 ; $i < count($tensArr); $i++)
{
    echo  $tensArr[$i]."\n" ;

}
```

Comment: to prevent running count() in each loop, a inital variable could be set: `for($i=0, $count=count($tensArr); $i < $count; $i++)`

Comment: @hakre , how is it different ? It does not seem to be even micro optimizing or correcting the code ? Please share your view.

Comment: @hakre , that does not help pretty much. Count function is 0(1) , see more here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566314/php-what-is-the-complexity-i-e-o1-on-of-the-function-count

Comment: MO. As you were assigning `$tensArr`, I thought it would complete the picture a bit more.

Comment: @hakre.. yeah that way it does help.