# How to convert a result set to an array of objects with Codeigniter's Active Record?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, resultset

This is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['page_title'] = 'Home';
    $data['new_grievances'] = $this->admin_home->get_members();
    $data['num_row'] = count($data['new_grievances'] );
    print_r($data['new_grievances']);
    print_r($data['num_row']);
    $this->load->view('admin/grievances_admin_home' , $data);
}
```

This is my model:

```
function get_members() {
    // $query = $this->db->get('enquiry');
    // return $query;
    $this->db->from('enquiry a');
    $this->db->join('enquiry_department b', 'a.department=b.id' , 'inner');
    $this->db->join('enquiry_user_type c', 'a.user_type=c.id' , 'inner');
    $this->db->WHERE('a.status IS NULL');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query;
}
```

I want to get the rows and and count of the number of rows.

Here, I execute the query **$data['new_grievances']** number of rows is 0 and so output of **$data['num_row']** must return zero.

When I have a result with at least one row, then I print the **$data['new_grievances']** value it gives:

> ```
> CI_DB_mysqli_result Object (
>     [conn_id] => mysqli Object (
>         [affected_rows] => 0
>         [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $ 
>         [client_version] => 50011
>         [connect_errno] => 0
>         [connect_error] =>
>         [errno] => 0
>         [error] =>
>         [error_list] => Array ( )
>         [field_count] => 12
>         [host_info]
>         ...
> ```

How do I get the rows in the result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code from `return $query;` to `return $query->result();` by this you can also use your `$data` inside the view also and count the total results in your controller.

This is controller

```
public function index()
{
    $data['page_title'] = 'Home';
    $data['new_grievances'] = $this->admin_home->get_members();
    $data['num_row'] = count($data['new_grievances'] );
    print_r($data['new_grievances']);
    print_r($data['num_row']);
    $this->load->view('admin/grievances_admin_home' , $data);
}
```

This is my model

```
function get_members() {
    $this->db->from('enquiry a');
    $this->db->join('enquiry_department b', 'a.department=b.id' , 'inner');
    $this->db->join('enquiry_user_type c', 'a.user_type=c.id' , 'inner');
    $this->db->WHERE('a.status IS NULL');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: If there is no row in the database then you will get error Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: @user9437856 then you have done something differently/incorrectly.  Codeigniter's `result()` method unconditionally returns an array.  If there are no rows in the result set, then it returns an empty array.  If there are rows in the result set, then it will return an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below lines.

```
public function index()
{
    $data['page_title'] = 'Home';
    $new_grievances = $this->admin_home->get_members();
    $data['num_row'] = $new_grievances->num_rows();
    print_r($new_grievances->result());
    $data['new_grievances'] = $new_grievances->result()
    print_r($data['num_row']);
    $this->load->view('admin/grievances_admin_home' , $data);
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the below line to get your results from DB

$query = $this->db->get();
$results = $query->result();

and use the below code to get number of rows found
$count = $query->num_rows();

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    $data['page_title'] = 'Home';
    $data['new_grievances'] = $this->admin_home->get_members();
    /*Old Code
    $data['num_row'] = count($data['new_grievances'] );*/
    //New Code
    $data['num_row'] = $data['new_grievances'];
    print_r($data['new_grievances']);
    print_r($data['num_row']);
    $this->load->view('admin/grievances_admin_home' , $data);
}
```

Model

```
function get_members() {
    $this->db->from('enquiry a');
    $this->db->join('enquiry_department b', 'a.department=b.id' , 'inner');
    $this->db->join('enquiry_user_type c', 'a.user_type=c.id' , 'inner');
    $this->db->WHERE('a.status IS NULL');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Comment: The OP clearly stated: `i want to get the rows and and count of the number of rows.`  This means that your unexplained answer does not deliver the required data and is therefore incorrect and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64923732/2943403), as long as you are only *using* the row count in one layer of your MVC structure, there is no real gain in declaring a count variable.

- If you are only going to use the value in your View, then only call `count()` in your View.
- If you are only going to use the value in your Controller, then only call `count()` in your Controller.
- If you need the row count in both the Controller AND the View, then write D.R.Y. code and cache the row count as a variable in the Controller, then pass it to the View.

Ultimately, I'm recommending that you not bloat the variable scope with data that is instantly accessible with a O(1) function call.