# How to find whether a json array is empty or not?

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to find whether a json array is empty or not using PHP?
empty($jsonarray) seems doesn't work!

Comment: Seriously, since when did PHP have json arrays?  Never heard of them before.

Comment: empty(json_decode($jsonarray))

Comment: Yup, that's most likely what was intended...

Comment: This is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2216063

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have decoded the JSON, yes it does.

```
<?php
    $json = '{"hello": ["world"], "goodbye": []}';
    $decoded = json_decode($json);
    print "Is hello empty? " . empty($decoded->{'hello'});
    print "\n";
    print "Is goodbye empty? " . empty($decoded->{'world'});
    print "\n";
?>
```

gives:

> Is hello empty?  
>   Is goodbye empty? 1

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
if(count(json_decode($jsonarray,1))==0) {
    echo "empty";
}

//or
if(empty(json_decode($jsonarray,1))) {
    echo "empty";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty JSON array's value is simply [], so you can search for it after the name of the array or in the string if you prints out an array.