# array_key_exists($key, $array) vs !empty($array[$key])

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

I've seen a lot of people do the former, is there any performance benefit doing one vs the other? Or is it just an eye candy? I personally use the latter every time as it is shorter and personally more readable to me.

Comment: Note, both statements are not equal. If $array[$key] is "" or 0, it is empty but the key still exists.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The other responses focus on the differences between the two functions. This is true, but if the source array does not contain `null` or `0` or `""`, ... (empty values) values you can benchmark the speed of the two functions:

```
<?php

function makeRandomArray( $length ) {
    $array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $array[$i] = rand(1, $length);
    }

    return $array;
}

function benchmark( $count, $function ) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $function();
    }
    return microtime(true) - $start;
}

$runs = 100000;
$smallLength = 10;
$small = makeRandomArray($smallLength);

var_dump(benchmark($runs, function() {
    global $small, $smallLength;
    array_key_exists(rand(0, $smallLength), $small);
}));
var_dump(benchmark($runs, function() {
    global $small, $smallLength;
    !empty($small[rand(0, $smallLength)]);
}));
```

Which gave me the following results:

For a small array:

- `array_key_exists`: float(0.18357992172241)
- `empty`: float(0.072798013687134)
- `isset`: float(0.070242881774902)

For a relative big array:

- `array_key_exists`: float(0.57489585876465)
- `empty`: float(0.0068421363830566)
- `isset`: float(0.0069410800933838)

So if it's possible it's faster to use `empty` or `isset`.

Although, I would like to highlight that this is a micro-optimization and that most probably won't matter that much. You need to actually do proper profiling, to find where is the bottleneck in your application before you end up focusing on these small optimizations.

Comment: `array_key_exists`, `isset` and `empty` behaves in a very different way. It shouldn't be a matter of performance only

Comment: Such performance difference is because isset() and empty() are language constructs while array_key_exists() is regular built-in function.

Comment: There is no performance difference (anymore) between array_key_exists and empty according to your code (PHP 8.1).

Answer (score 16):

`array_key_exists($key, $array)` and `!empty($array[$key])` can produce different results therefore ***it is not a matter of performance or preference***.

| $array[$key] | array_key_exists($key, $array) | !empty($array[$key]) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| does not exist | false | false |
| is truthy | true | true |
| is falsey | true | false |

You can see that the truth table is different for falsey values (false, 0, NULL, etc). Therefore `!empty($array[$key])` is not suitable in situations where a falsey value could be considered *present* e.g. `$array["number_of_children"]` should not be tested for emptiness where the value 0 makes sense.

---

You can use `isset($array[$key])` which produces results identical to `array_key_exists($key, $array)` with exactly one exception:

| $array[$key] | array_key_exists($key, $array) | isset($array[$key]) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| does not exist | false | false |
| is truthy | true | true |
| is falsey but not NULL | true | true |
| is NULL | true | false |

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = array(
    'foo' => null
);

echo (int)!empty($array['foo']); // 0
echo (int)array_key_exists('foo', $array); // 1
```

Comment: Same applies to `isset`: `isset($array['foo'])` will yield false.

Answer (score 1):

They both are different

`array_key_exists($key, $array)` checks whether the key exist in the array and returns TRUE if the given key is set in the array.

whereas

`!empty($array[$key])` Determine whether a variable value is empty or not