# PHP: know if a value from explode is set

Tags: php, explode

http://codepad.org/GAl6W6xn

Why does this code say "not set"? What is array location 2 set as to make it say "set"? How can I approach this so I know if there is or isn't a value in location 2?

(sorry for lack of a good title, couldn't think of one)

Comment: Um, there is a value there, it just happens to be an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is

[**array_key_exists**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)
[**empty**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

**Try this**

```
array_key_exists(2, $r);
// or
!empty($r[2]);
```

For more accurate

```
$line = "a";
$r = explode("|",$line);

print_r($r);
if(!empty($r[2])) // or use if(array_key_exists(2, $r))
    echo "array location [2] set";
else echo "array location [2] NOT set";
```

Comment: What is the difference between array_key_exists and empty?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884609/array-key-existskey-array-vs-emptyarraykey . It will explain you better..

Comment: `array_key_exists` does not solve the original problem. Change `$line = "a";` in your example to `$line = "a||c";` and `array location [2] set` will be output, which is the same problem `isset` was causing.

Comment: @lightster Thanks for explaining the same as what was explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884609/array-key-existskey-array-vs-emptyarraykey mentioned in the 2nd comment...I totally accept on what yo said but in this case you can use `array_key_exists` too.

Comment: @Wazzzy I'm sorry, my example was wrong. Try this: change `$line = "a";` to `$line = "a|||c";`. You will see that `!empty($r[2])` and `array_key_exists(2, $r)` do not return the same results in that case.

Answer (score 6):

well it is set, perhaps you meant to check if it was [empty()](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

you should probably have a look at : [The type comparison tables](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 3):

you can try

`if(!empty($r[2]))`