# Check if array is not empty

Tags: php, arrays

********Update**********

`var_dump: string(0)` ""

I am trying to check if part of an array is not empty then display code but the code get's displayed anyway.

I have tried `!is_null !empty`. I am not really sure which should be correct or should I go with: 
`if (sizeof($book['Booking']['comments'])>0)`

**Code:**

```
<?php if (!empty($book['Booking']['comments'])) {?>
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family:'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#666666;">
                    <?=$book['Booking']['comments']?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<? } ?>
```

**Array:**

```
Array
(
[Booking] => Array
    (
        [id] => 109
        [user_id] => 1
        [corporate_account_id] => 0
        [id_ref] => RES000109
        [price] => 178.00
        [arrival] => 2011-10-18 00:00:00
        [departure] => 2011-10-19 00:00:00
        [rate_title] => 
        [adult_guests] => 4
        [child_guests] => 0
        [company] => gravitate
        [titlename] => 
        [firstname] => John
        [surname] => Doe
        [address1] => 123 Fake St
        [address2] => 
        [city] => New York
        [state] => NY
        [postcode] => 12345
        [country] => US
        [phone] => 1111111111
        [mobile] => 
        [fax] => 
        [email] => example@example.com
        [comments] => 
        [created] => 2011-10-18 13:40:47
        [updated] => 2011-10-18 13:40:47
        [status] => 1
        [cancelled] => 0
        [request_src] => website
        [request_token] => 0
        [token] => ayzrGnx
        [survey_sent] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [survey_returned] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [send_sms] => 0
        [payment_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [fullname] =>  John Doe
    )
```

Comment: What's the type of `comments` supposed to be? `empty` should work fine in all cases except when you have a string composed entirely of whitespace.

Comment: What `var_dump($book['Booking']['comments'])` gives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a PHP array is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-tell-if-a-php-array-is-empty)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect it may contain `(bool) FALSE`, which is not true for `is_null()`.

Try simply:

```
if ($book['Booking']['comments']) {
```

This should also work for anything that evaluates to `FALSE`, like an empty string.

Comment: `which is not true for empty()` - who said you that?

Comment: `if (!$book['Booking']['comments']) {` will do the opposite.

Comment: Whoa! Two months took you to correct one statement ;) What about other one?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel somebody +1ed me for it randomly, to be honest I haven't re-visited this page since I wrote this, and I have admit this is *not* the best answer here... but it might as well be correct in it's inadequacy...

Answer (score 3):

`if (count($book['Booking']['comments']) > 0) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

your question is too localized. There is some typo in your code or something like that.

There is absolutely **no difference** what to use in your case, `if (!empty($var))` or `if ($var)`. So, `if ($book['Booking']['comments']) {` worked, there was no problem with your `if (!empty($book['Booking']['comments']))` too. So, there was no poin in the question at all.

All these answers trying to answer this not-a-real-question are nonsense.

the only issue can be a space symbol mentioned by jotorres1, but you have already said there are none.

Answer (score 2):

`!empty($var)`, `count($var) > 0`, `!$var`, all of these will work in most situations. empty() has the "advantage" of not throwing a notice when the given variable / array key doesn't exist, but if you don't have to worry about that a boolean check (`!$var`) should suffice (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) which types convert to FALSE). It also happens to be the shortest in code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `$book['Booking']['comments']` is even an array in this case. So you could just use `strlen`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

`<?php if (strlen($book['Booking']['comments'])) {?>`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to `trim()` that property to remove any whitespace before testing if it is `empty()`.

Edit: I'm assuming it is a string. It doesn't look like an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

that is not an array for sure.

do `var_dump($book["Booking"]["comments"])` to check the data type accordingly

Comment: then you should just do - if($book["Booking"]["comments"] == "")

Comment: I would like to display the code if it is not empty would I use ===? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use this following logic, and try to make it a little bit simpler.

```
<?php 
    // Only change this
    // and leave everything else as is
    $book_comment = $book['Booking']['comments'];
    $book_comment = trim($book_comment);
    // The reason I use empty trim, is to take 
    // away any space.  
    // In the output, use the original $book['Booking']['comments']

    if(!empty($book_comment)):?>

      <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#666666;">
                      <?=$book['Booking']['comments']?>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
<?php endif;?>
```

I have not tested this, as I can't right now, but hopefully that should somewhat help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Empty array:

   `$array = array();`

   `reset($array)` returns `FALSE`.
2. Populated array:

   `$array = array('foo', 'bar');`

   `reset($array)` returns first element (`'foo'`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ascertain whether the variable you are testing is actually explicitly an not empty array, you could use something like this:

```
if ($book['Booking']['comments'] !== array()) {
  //your logic goes here
  ....................
}
```

This logic is more faster from others solution. Also it will maintain coding standard.