# How do i check if a declare array is empty?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called **tagcat** , like so

```
$tagcat = array();

....
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    $tagcat[$tagid] = array('tagname'=>$tagname, 'taghref'=>$taghref);
}
```

Using print_r($tagcat) i get the following result set

```
   Array ( [] => Array ( [tagname] => [taghref] => ) )
```

Using var_dump($tagcat), i get

```
array(1) { [""]=> array(2) { ["tagname"]=> NULL ["taghref"]=> NULL } }
```

In php, i want to check if the array is empty. But when using the following conditions, it always finds something in the array, which is not true!

```
if ( isset($tagcat) ) {
    echo 'array is NOT empty';
} else {
    echo 'EMPTY!!!';
}

if ( !empty($tagcat) ) {
    echo 'array is NOT empty';
} else {
    echo 'EMPTY!!!';
}
```

How do i check if the array is empty?

Comment: What do you get if you do `print_r(tagcat);`. Also I'm assuming that you meant the `tagcat` to be a definition not a variable because you have no `$` in front of it. Is there more code to show?

Comment: @Henders fixed the typo + also edited the question to answer your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a PHP array is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-tell-if-a-php-array-is-empty)

Comment: Do you want to check if the array `$tagcat` is empty or if the array containing `tagname` and `taghref ` inside the array `$tagcat` is empty ? If you have nested arrays, be sure you're checking the correct array.

Comment: @HiDeo i edited the question to answer your question

Comment: It's still unclear how exactly you define "empty". The array is clearly not empty according to PHP's definition of "empty". What's *your* definition exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
if(!array_filter($array)) {
  echo "Array is empty";
}
```

This was to check for the single array. For multi-dimensional array in your case. I think this should work:

```
$empty = 0;
foreach ($array as $val) {
  if(!array_filter($val)) {
    $empty = 1;
  }
}

if ($empty) {
  echo "Array is Empty";
}
```

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of $array equal to FALSE will be removed.

With this it only returns the value which are not empty. See more in the docs example **Example #2 array_filter() without callback**

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if there are ANY elements in the array

```
if (!empty($tagcat) ) { //its $tagcat, not tagcat
    echo 'array is NOT empty';
} else {
    echo 'EMPTY!!!';
}
```

Also, if you need to empty the values before checking

```
foreach ($tagcat as $cat => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
       unset($tagcat[$cat]);
    }
}
if (empty($tagcat)) {
   //empty array
}
```

Hope it helps

EDIT: I see that you have edited your $tagcat var. So, validate with vardump($tagcat) your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($array)) {
 // array is empty.
 }
```

if you want remove empty elements try  this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if (empty($value)) {
     unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```