# how to check if ADOdb recordset is empty

Tags: testing, recordset, is-empty, adodb-php

I ran into the problem while checking emptiness of the `ADODB5` recordset

```
$db = ADONewConnection($dbdriver);
$db->Connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$rs = $db->Execute($query);
```

now, if I try to check recordset

```
if(isset($rs[0]))
...
...
```

I get the error `Cannot use object of type ADORecordSet_mysqli as array`

How do you check whether returned recordset is or isn't empty?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-check-whether-an-array-is-empty-using-php help?

Comment: Yes and No. However, I just figured it out.

Comment: thank you for providing the answer you figured out. it helps other people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before `isset` evaluation I converted ADODB recordset to array

```
$ra = $rs->getRows();
```

then tested if `$ra` array is empty

```
if(empty($ra)){
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `$db->Execute($query)` method fails, it may not return a ADORecordSet object. I would not call the `$rs->getRows()` method before being sure `$rs` is valid, so,

```
if (is_subclass_of($rs, 'ADORecordSet') AND $rs->recordCount()) {
    // I have rows
    // ...
}
```