# PHP Laravel Check if Array is empty

Tags: php, laravel

I am struggling with displaying some content depending on if an array does have a value or not.Every time the code in the else part is executed. What's wrong here? Is there any syntax error with this code? I'm using php laravel.

```
foreach($now as $v)
{
        $arry[$c++]=$v->Code; 
}
if($arry==null){
     Do Something
}
else{
     Do Something else
}
```

Comment: you should check array's `length` rather than comparing with `null`

Comment: check for `empty`? Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-check-whether-an-array-is-empty-using-php

Comment: if you want to check that array is empty you should use `empty($arry)` or `$arry === []` construction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether an array is empty using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-check-whether-an-array-is-empty-using-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( sizeof($arry) ) { // If more than 0
   // Do Something
} else { // If 0
   // Do Something else
}
```

Comment: Note that in PHP `sizeof()` is NOT what you may think it is based on your experience from i.e. `C`. It's just **alias** for `count()`. Luckily, since IIRC PHP5 array counter is maintained internally, but prior that change it was really iterating over all the elements counting. So beware underlying implementation. Also this code is showing the intent. You do not care how many elements you have. You want to know it is not empty, so you should have written `if (!empty($arry)) {... not empty....} else { .... }`

Answer (score 7):

```
if($arry) {
     echo 'The array is not empty';
}
else {
     echo 'The array is empty';
}
```

For more: [How can you check if an array is empty?](https://www.quora.com/In-PHP-how-can-you-check-if-an-array-is-empty)

Answer (score 3):

Better to do `if (!empty($arry)) {}`

P.S. yes `if (!$arry)` do the same, but every person which is not familiar with php or even have little understanding of programming, should understand the code. Whats mean "not array", but if it will be "not empty array" is more clear. It is very straight forward.

Clean code

Answer (score 0):

Always check array before iterate in foreach and check with count function to check its value

```
if(isset($now) && count($now)>0){
    foreach($now as $v) {
            $arry[$c++]=$v->Code; 
    }
}
if(count($arry)>0){
     Do Something
}
else{
     Do Something else
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `empty()` or `count()` or `sizeof()` as below :

```
$a = [];
if(empty($a)) {
    echo 'empty' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '!empty' . PHP_EOL;
}
if(count($a) == 0) {
    echo 'empty' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '!empty' . PHP_EOL;
}
if(sizeof($a) == 0) {
    echo 'empty' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '!empty' . PHP_EOL;
}

echo empty($a) . PHP_EOL; // 1
echo count($a) . PHP_EOL; // 0
echo sizeof($a) . PHP_EOL; // 0

Output : 
empty
empty
empty
1
0
0
```

Answer (score -2):

this is not related to Laravel framework

```
if (count($arry) > 0) 
   Do Something
else
   Do Something else
```