# How can I check if my repository contains data?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I like to check if there is data in the repository:

```
$dataCollection = $this->em->getRepository(Data::class)->DataConnector($fieldId,$id);

if(isset($dataCollection)){
    echo "this contains data";
} else {
   echo "this does not contain data";
}
```

But even if no data is in the repository, I always get the message "this contains data".

Comment: [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php): '*Determine if a variable is declared and is different than NULL*', are you sure you need `isset`? What is the dumped value of `$dataCollection`?

Comment: What's the definition for `DataConnector`? I think that's not a standard doctrine method.

Comment: @Script47 this is the dump value of dataCollection: `[]`

Comment: won't this always result in a valid isset() statement? You basically always have a repository item anyways

Comment: Why not check using `!empty($dataCollection)`, then?

Comment: @yivi yes "empty" is working. I think I have difficulties unerstanding "isset"

Comment: Dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-check-whether-an-array-is-empty-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output (`[]`) is an empty array. An empty array IS set:

```
$x = [];

print_r(isset($x)); // 1
print_r(empty($x)); // 1
print_r(count($x)); // 0
```

You need either [`count`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) or [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Answer (score -2):

```
$dataCollection = $this->em->getRepository(Data::class)->DataConnector($fieldId,$id);

if(dataCollection != NULL){
    echo "this contains data";
} else {
   echo "this does not contain data";
}
```

Comment: What does this answer achieve? What do you think `isset` does?

Comment: I just copy and paste. I saw 'isset' mistake on code when I posted my answer. So, I edited my answer.

Comment: What `isset` mistake?

Comment: It is not necessary

Comment: Do you understand what `isset` does?