# PHP—Does array evaluate to empty after removing last element?

Tags: php, arrays, is-empty

I am removing an element from an array in PHP:

```
$images = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'no-image.jpg');
if (in_array('no-image.jpg', $images)) {
  $imgIndex = array_search('no-image.jpg', $images);
  array_splice($images, $imgIndex, 1);
}
```

And then I am checking to make sure the `$images` array isn't empty:

```
if (!empty($images)) {
  //Some code
}
```

But if my array only contains `no-image.jpg` and I remove it, will `empty()` return true or false?

Comment: try it and see?

Comment: yes it returns true but you can check it yourself it will take much less time checking than waiting for answer

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I did :)

Comment: Next time just try: `var_dump(empty($images));` it will tell you.

Comment: @Bossman I DID try this all before posting, I just posted a question/answer for future searchers because I couldn't find information about it when I searched for it.

Comment: @jameson2012 I DID try this all before posting, I just posted a question/answer for future searchers because I couldn't find information about it when I searched for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-check-whether-an-array-is-empty-using-php

Comment: @CBroe, I knew that an empty array evaluated to empty but I didn't know if it was different if you spliced it like I was doing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your array will evaluate to empty. From the PHP manual:

```
The following values are considered to be empty:

"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
```

So:

```
$images = array('no-image.jpg');
if (in_array('no-image.jpg', $images)) {
  $imgIndex = array_search('no-image.jpg', $images);
  array_splice($images, $imgIndex, 1);
}
echo var_dump(empty($arr)); //Will output bool(true)
```

And:

```
$images = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'no-image.jpg');
if (in_array('no-image.jpg', $images)) {
  $imgIndex = array_search('no-image.jpg', $images);
  array_splice($images, $imgIndex, 1);
}
echo var_dump(empty($arr)); //Will output bool(false)
```

Comment: it's not usually a good idea to post questions that are just something you could/should try and then answer your own question - that's probably going to get you a lot of downvotes :-)

Comment: @jameson2012, I've been helped a lot by question/answer posts that ask simple questions that can be easily figured out with a little testing and they weren't downvoted so I figured I'd pass the favor on :)

Answer (score 0):

An aside - you could swap out the in_array, search and splice for a search and unset.

```
<?php    
$images = ['no-image.jpg'];
$imgIndex = array_search('no-image.jpg', $images);
if($imgIndex !== false) {
    unset($images[$imgIndex]);
}

var_dump($images);
var_dump(empty($images));
```

Output:

```
array(0) {
}
bool(true)
```

You can use unset, if you don't care for the re-indexing that array_splice affords you.

Comment: I actually chose array_splice because I need the array to be reindexed

Comment: Fair enough, you may get minor performance gains with an equivalent unset followed by array_values.  But you can still drop the in_array followed by array_search for just the array_search.  Negligible gains.